# Select2 dropdown menu persists after select removed from DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am using select2 version 4.0.2(rc1)
What I am seeing is that when using select2 with `isMultple=true`, opening the dropdown and then dynamically removing the select from the DOM, the menu sticks around.

You can see it happening in [the select2 examples](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#multiple) by focusing on control so you see the time zone options, then in the console typing `$('.s2-example').remove()`. The list of options sticks around.

**Edit**: Above is an example of what I am trying to work around. What is happening in my case is the dom is being manipulated to remove the select box by a framework in such a way that I can't hook into it before it happens. What I am trying to do is find a way to respond to the element being removed in the hopes that I can manually remove the options list if it exists.

I'm trying to figure out a clean approach to handling this. I've tried hooking into destroy like so:

`$("#select-2-id").on("destroy", function(){...})`

but destroy doesn't appear to be fired.

I have considered using a [mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) but that feels kind of hacky to me. Could anyone suggest a better way to handle this? Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Definitely [buried in the documentation (under adapters)](https://select2.github.io/options-old.html#adapters-all), but you should be calling the `destroy` method on the select by passing "destroy" to the jQuery object's `.select2()` method

```
$(".js-example-basic-multiple").select2('destroy');
```

This destroys the instance.  You can then safely call `.remove()`

```
$(".js-example-basic-multiple").select2('destroy').remove();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. That doesn't quite help with my case though I think. In my case the control is being removed from the dom by a framework in a way that I can't hook in before it happens. I've edited my question.

Comment: @TheMethod So you can't hook into it before it happens.  With such a destructive action taking place, I can't see any way you can get around this without using a [mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) or a [DOM mutation event](http://help.dottoro.com/ljqkbipq.php), the second of which is highly discouraged.  Those event listeners have been deprecated.